# Populating Images from WP7 Gallery to ImageList

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7

I want to populate all the images from gallery to imagelist so that my app can display all the images once my application launches. Please let me know how to do it in C#

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can access the MediaLibrary with the [MediaLibrary](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xna.framework.media.medialibrary.aspx) class. If you want a more detailed answer, ask a more detailed question.

Comment: I guess you have got me wrong .... I have created a list (ie ImageList) which I want to populate by reading the image one by one from the gallery. something like this imagelist=Read(Image Source)

Comment: You do not make sense on any level whatsoever.